# Memory-mapped image is that possible on iOS?

Tags: ios, image, memory, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

Today I woke up with something that I thought was a big idea or a totally stupid one. I need to write an iOS application that uses huge scrollable images about 5k pixel squares, due to memory limit is not possible to load such big images on iOS. 
I do know about `CATileLayer`, but the small lag doesn't fit my requirements.
So I thought it would be possible to memory map the file and read the image from it. Unfortunately it doesn't work, here is the code snipped:

```
    NSError * __autoreleasing error = nil;
    NSData * mappedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tigerbig" ofType:@"png"] options:NSDataReadingMappedAlways | NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
    UIImage * thebigImage =[UIImage imageWithData:mappedData];
    self.imageView.image = thebigImage;
```

Everything seems to work until the image view has to display the big image. For what I remember `UIImage` is a tiny wrapper around `CGImage` and it doesn't load the image until the image needs to be rendered.
Probably in the sequence of creating the image from the `NSData`, data are copied into RAM triggering a memory warning than the app crashes. 
So I've tried also varius combination using `ImageIO` and `CGDataProvider`s without any success. 
 Now I'm telling myself that the main idea was probably completely wrong, can someone point me in right direction?

Comment: Loading a huge image into `UIImage` is definitely the problem. It doesn't matter if it's a "tiny wrapper around CGImage" or not. The solution is definitely a tiling. You address the delay issue through (a) clever preloading of all of the probable "next tiles" as well as (b) asynchronous loading of next "next tiles". Whether you use `CATiledLayer` or do something else (http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/catiledlayer-how-to-use-it-how-it-works-what-it-does/) is up to you, but something along these lines is undoubtedly where you want to go.

Comment: Hi Rob thanks for your suggestions and the useful link, I also found pretty interesting the approach using an OpenGL rendering. I imagine that you map different texture using crop functions into a 2d big model. That's really interesting, but I'm to noob in OGL (ios too maybe ;-) )